# Is it possible to package into single whl, both main package and sub package (with setup.py), listed as a dependency for main package?

Tags: python, python-poetry, python-wheel

Let's consider the following directory structure

```
+-main_package
+-sub_package
  +- setup.py
pyproject.toml
```

In `pyproject.toml`, the sub_package is listed as dependency

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
sub_package= { path = "./sub_package", develop = true }
```

Also, there is setup.py file in `sub_package` with some entry points

```
setup(
    entry_points={
        'foo': [
            'bar = sub_package.bar.baz',
        ],
    }
)
```

Means those entry points should be considering while installing the whole wheel.

Is it ok just to add to `pyproject.toml`

```
packages = [
    { include = "main_package" },
    { include = "sub_package" },
]
```

Is it possible at all to package such structure into single wheel?

UPD

`poetry build` successfully builds single whl `main_package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl` file for both packages, and then I can install it into fresh venv with

```
pip install package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

during which the sub-package is built

```
Building wheels for collected packages: sub_package
  Building wheel for sub_package (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for sub_package: filename=sub_package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Stored in directory: ...
Successfully built sub_package
Installing collected packages: sub_package, main_package
Successfully installed main_package-0.1.0 sub_package-0.1.0
```

but after uploading to private pypi index and attempt to install it with

```
pip install main_package --extra-index-url http://...
```

no intermediate build is performed and installation failed with

```
Collecting main_package==0.1.0
  Using cached main_package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (211 kB)
Processing c:\builds\...\main_package\sub_package
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\builds\...\main_package\sub_package'
```

Any ideas?

UPD2

Installation from local whl is succeeded because pip builds sub_package from **original** directory on my PC 8-/ So as soon as I remove it I got the same error.

I look into whl file, there are both `main_package` and `sub_package` (including setup.py and all metadata, necessary to build) as expected, **but** in `METADATA` there is reference to `sub_package` with **absolute path**!

```
Requires-Dist: sub_package @ file:///C:/Users/anton/Documents/main_package/sub_package
```

My mind is off, is there poetry issue or I am doing something completely wrong?